# httr github-API callback URL issues

Tags: r, github, github-api, httr

I am using the `httr` v0.2 package to use the github api as well now. But I am struggling to get past the `oauth2.0(...)` part in which I get to the browser page for my app, click on 'Allow' and then get redirected to the callback URL page.

The httr github demo suggests using the callback URL as `http://localhost:1410` but when I get redirected to that page, google chrome suggests that it could not connect to the page and the page it is getting re-directed to is `http://localhost:1410/?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&state=DZNFcm8tnq`...so I tried a bunch of other ports and overall URLS to no success...

What would be another callback URL and URL that would work?

below is the code I used

```
require(httr)
## Loading required package: httr
github.app <- oauth_app("github","xxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
github.urls <- oauth_endpoint(NULL, "authorize", "access_token",base_url = "https://github.com/login/oauth")
github.token <- oauth2.0_token(github.urls,github.app)
## Loading required package: Rook
## Loading required package: tools
## Loading required package: brew
## starting httpd help server ... done
## Waiting for authentication in browser...
```

which is when I get directed to a page that has the 'Allow' button whichIi click after which I get redirected to the page in google chrome that cannot connect to localhost :1410

Answer (score 13):

You should update `httr` package to latest version (now it's 0.3 - available in CRAN). I found the relevant example from `httr` (version 0.3) demos:

```
library(httr)

# 1. Find OAuth settings for github:
#    http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/
oauth_endpoints("github")

# 2. Register an application at https://github.com/settings/applications
#    Insert your values below - if secret is omitted, it will look it up in
#    the GITHUB_CONSUMER_SECRET environmental variable.
#
#    Use http://localhost:1410 as the callback url
myapp <- oauth_app("github", "56b637a5baffac62cad9")

# 3. Get OAuth credentials
github_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("github"), myapp)

# 4. Use API
req <- GET("https://api.github.com/rate_limit", config(token = github_token))
stop_for_status(req)
content(req)
```

You can get it with `demo("oauth2-github", package = "httr", ask = FALSE)` command.

Comment: Very nice.  I had to install and load the httpuv package as well for it to work, but it went very smoothly from the error messages.

Comment: What was the end working script for this? I am having the same issue and this question doesn't have a posted solution. Thanks.

Comment: For me, the callback URL had to set as "http://localhost:1410/" (don't forget the last backslash).

Answer (score 0):

Are you serving this from a web app or is it an extension/plugin? The redirect url has to be from the same host as the callback url you specified when you set up the github application. See [here](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#redirect-urls) for more. If you are using the API in an extension then I won't be of much help. That's what I was looking for when I came across your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and problem exactly and the problem was solved by modifying the Homepage URL to the correct one as per the demo : http://github.com 
so eventually the problem was not in the callback URL it was in the Homepage URL, you might also use the cache=F argument in the oauth2.0_token() function.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. But after I installed httpuv package it worked fine. Once you install httpuv package, upon running this code,

> github_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("github"), myapp)

you should be able to see 'authentication complete'.